# Three.js - Clipping troika-three-text with clipping planes

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it possible to clip troika-three-text for threejs using clipping planes?

It doesn't seem to be working.

```
import { Text } from 'troika-three-text'

const minClippingPlane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0), 1)
const maxClippingPlane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0), 1)

const text = new Text()
text.text = "Hello"

text.material.clipPlanes = [minClippingPlane, maxClippingPlane]
text.material.clipIntersection = true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add cliping planes to Trioka Text you need do something like this:

```
const text = new Text()
text.text = "Hello"

const material = new MeshBasicMaterial({ color: new Color('red') });
material.clipPlanes = [minClippingPlane, maxClippingPlane]

text.material = material;
```

> Note that because your material instance is replaced by a derived
> material instance, any changes you make to your original material will
> not be reflected in the derived version. If you need to modify
> properties of the material afterward, be sure you get a new reference
> to the derived version:
> https://protectwise.github.io/troika/troika-three-text/#material